# Python ftplib error 426 when putting files on iSeries

Tags: python, python-2.7, ibm-midrange, ftplib

Have a peculiar issue that I can't seem to fix on my own..

I'm attempting to FTP a list of files in a directory over to an iSeries IFS using Python's ftplib library.

**Note, the files are in a single subdirectory down from the python script.**

Below is an excerpt of the code that is giving me trouble:

```
from ftplib import FTP
import os

localpath = os.getcwd() + '/Files/'

def putFiles():
    hostname = 'host.name.com'
    username = 'myuser'
    password = 'mypassword'
    myftp = FTP(hostname)
    myftp.login(username, password)
    myftp.cwd('/STUFF/HERE/')
        for file in os.listdir(localpath):
            if file.endswith('.csv'):
                try:
                    file = localpath + file
                    print 'Attempting to move ' + file
                    myftp.storbinary("STOR " + file, open(file, 'rb'))
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
```

The specific error that I am getting throw is:

```
Attempting to move /home/doug/Files/FILE.csv
426-Unable to open or create file /home/doug/Files to receive data.
426 Data transfer ended.
```

What I've done so far to troubleshoot:

1. Initially I thought this was a permissions issue on the directory containing my files. I used chmod 777 /home/doug/Files and re-ran my script, but the same exception occured.
2. Next I assumed there was an issue between my machine and the iSeries. I validated that I could indeed put files by using ftp. I was successfully able to put the file on the iSeries IFS using the shell FTP.

Thanks!

**Solution**

```
from ftplib import FTP
import os

localpath = os.getcwd() + '/Files/'

def putFiles():
    hostname = 'host.name.com'
    username = 'myuser'
    password = 'mypassword'
    myftp = FTP(hostname)
    myftp.login(username, password)
    myftp.cwd('/STUFF/HERE/')
        for csv in os.listdir(localpath):
            if csv.endswith('.csv'):
                try:
                    myftp.storbinary("STOR " + csv, open(localpath + csv, 'rb'))
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
```

Comment: I'm glad you got it working, but the solution you posted can't be exactly what you're using. Maybe you meant `csv.endswith('.csv')` instead of `file.endswith('.csv')`?

Comment: @JohnY Good catch, I missed that when posting the corrected code. Updated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, your code is trying to execute the following FTP command:

```
STOR /home/doug/Files/FILE.csv
```

Meaning it is trying to create `/home/doug/Files/FILE.csv` on the IFS. Is this what you want? I suspect that it isn't, given that you bothered to change the remote directory to `/STUFF/HERE/`.

If you are trying to issue the command

```
STOR FILE.csv
```

then you have to be careful how you deal with the Python variable that you've named `file`. In general, it's not recommended that you reassign a variable that is the target of a `for` loop, precisely because this type of confusion can occur. Choose a different variable name for `localpath + file`, and use that in your `open(..., 'rb')`.

Incidentally, it looks like you're using Python 2, since there is a bare `print` statement with no parentheses. I'm sure you're aware that Python 3 is recommended by now, but if you do stick to Python 2, it's recommended that you avoid using `file` as a variable name, because it actually means something in Python 2 (it's the name of a type; specifically, the return type of the `open` function).

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your response. I've made adjustments to the script to remove the file variable reference. Will update my question to include this: but the files are in a subdirectory relative to the script; this was the reason I was providing a path.

Whould I need to change directory (using shutils, or similar) down into that directory in order to perform the STOR?

Comment: It's evident from your code that the files you want to transfer from are in a subdirectory of the current local directory. It doesn't matter whether you change the current local directory or not. You just have to make sure you open the correct file in your `open` call, and have the correct target in the STOR command.

Comment: John, adding the path to the open per your suggestion was the key. Truly appreciate your guidance on this!